# React rerendering input on change and blur events, even though the internal state hasn't changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am experimenting around with React to get used to its whole ecosystem. Here's the code that I am currently working on to test how forms work:

```
function TextInput({
   name,
   value = '',
   required = false,
   ...props
}) {
   console.log('RENDERING');
   const [_value, setValue] = React.useState(value);
   console.log('_value', _value);

   function changeHandler(e) {
      setValue(e.target.value);
      console.log('change', e.target.value);
   }

   function blurHandler(e) {
      setValue(e.target.value);
      console.log('blur', e.target.value);
   }

   function focusHandler(e) {
      setValue(e.target.value);
      console.log('focus', e.target.value);
   }

   return <div className="form-group">
      <input type="text" name={name} value={_value} onBlur={blurHandler} onChange={changeHandler} onFocus={focusHandler} {...props}></input>
      <div className="form-error"></div>
   </div>
}

function App() {
   return <>
      <h1>Simple forms / validation</h1>
      <TextInput name="name" placeholder="simple"></TextInput>
   </>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have read that React doesn't rerender a given component upon a state change if the previous state value and the new state value are both the same. This makes perfect sense and so does the inspections that I do in the code.

However, I don't really understand as to why does React re-render the given component when the `blur` event occurs. Technically, when the `blur` event fires, the `setValue(e.target.value)` call makes the state change and since the previous state value is the same as this new one, there ideally shouldn't be any rerender.

But the console logs shows that there is a re-render. I want to know why does this happen, or is it some kind of a bug.

Comment: I am curious too so I made a [sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bkf85z?file=src/App.js) to test this. It seems to me that just spamming `focus` and  `blur` does not trigger the re-render, but if **edit the input and  `blur`** it does trigger the re-render. Not sure why this behavior though.

Comment: @JohnLi yes exactly, you're right. `blur` only causes a re-render when there is a prior `change` event.